# Get current routing value while mapping the route by default in ASP.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core, url-routing

I have multi language .net core website, i use custom route for some pages, and i stored routes in startup, so i can use tag helpers like Url.Action and asp-action,
the problem is i used {culture} variable in route, i passed a default value in startup for it, but when i change the language of the website from "ar" to "en", the value still the default in the other language,
for example :
the result for this url

> http://localhost:14896/en/content/pages/8

when using the tag helper :

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Details", "Content", new { id = item.ContentId, perma = _helper.GetPermaLink(contentLoc: item) })">@_loc["More"]</a>
```

result :

> /ar/page/test-2/2

and the result for this url

> http://localhost:14896/ar/content/pages/8
> is the same:

> /ar/page/test-2/2

My startup configuration is :

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        //app.ConfigureExceptionHandler();
    }
    else
    {
        //Global error handling instead of try, catch
        app.ConfigureExceptionHandler();

        //app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.AddLocalizationBuilder();

    //app.UseHttpsRedirection();

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");

    string defaultCulture = _config.GetValue<string>("DefaultCulture");
    string currentCulture = defaultCulture;
    app.Use((context, next) =>
    {
        string routeCulture = context.Request.RouteValues["culture"].ToString();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(routeCulture))
            currentCulture = routeCulture;
        return next.Invoke();
    });
            
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllerRoute("ContentList", "{culture}/content/{perma}/{id}", new { controller = "Content", action = "List", culture = currentCulture });
        endpoints.MapControllerRoute("ContentDetails", "{culture}/page/{perma}/{id}",new { controller = "Content", action = "Details", culture = currentCulture });

        endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "areas",
            pattern: "{culture:culture}/{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

        endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "default",
            pattern: "{culture:culture}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

        endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "default",
            pattern: "{*catchall}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "RedirectToDefaultLanguage", culture = defaultCulture });
    });
}
```

Comment: So you mean when you change the culture by changing the url,the href of <a></a> does not change?

Comment: yes, culture still the same only on href

Comment: I know that i can fix it by providing the current culture on each Url.Action helper, but i need to do it as a common scenario

Comment: If you try to use `{culture}` to replace `{culture:culture}`,can it work?

Comment: no, i tried and it didn't work